# snakemake rule to delete file

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a large snakemake file that looks like this (after simplifying a lot).

```
rule a:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.a.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule b:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.b.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule c:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.c.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule d:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.d.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule all:
    input: 'raw1.a.b.c.a.d.csv',
           'raw2.a.b.c.d.a.csv'
```

(This setup lets me use rules like functions, by chaining their filename suffixes in the `all` rule.)

Starting state:

```
$ ls -tr1
Snakefile
raw1.csv
raw2.csv

$ snakemake all
...
```

After:

```
$ ls -tr1
Snakefile
raw1.csv
raw2.csv
raw2.a.csv
raw2.a.b.csv
raw2.a.b.c.csv
raw2.a.b.c.d.csv
raw1.a.csv
raw1.a.b.csv
raw1.a.b.c.csv
raw1.a.b.c.a.csv
raw1.a.b.c.a.d.csv
raw2.a.b.c.d.a.csv
```

Now, I'd like to *add* a rule that deletes specific intermediate files (for example `raw1.a.csv` and `raw2.a.b.csv`) because I don't need them and they take up a lot of disk space. I can't mark the outputs with `temp()` because of the wildcard `{path}`.

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: `temp` does work for outputs containing wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

`temp()` does work in this scenario.

```
rule all:
    input: 'raw1.a.b.c.a.d.csv',
        'raw2.a.b.c.d.a.csv'

rule a:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: temp('{path}.a.csv')
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule b:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.b.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule c:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: temp('{path}.c.csv')
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule d:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.d.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
```

Executing this would result in creation of files `raw1.a.b.c.a.d.csv , raw1.a.b.csv, raw2.a.b.c.d.csv, raw2.a.b.csv` and auto-deletion of files `raw1.a.csv, raw2.a.csv, raw1.a.b.c.csv, raw2.a.b.c.csv, raw1.a.b.c.a.csv, raw2.a.b.c.d.a.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually, this solution doesn't work.. it results in race condition...

---

Ok, I figured it out...

```
rule a:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.a.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule b:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.b.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule c:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.c.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule d:
    input: '{path}.csv'
    output: '{path}.d.csv'
    shell: 'cp {input} {output}'
rule remove:                          # <-- rule to delete a file
    input: '{path}'
    output: touch('{path}.removed')
    shell: 'rm {input}'
rule all:
    input: 'raw1.a.b.c.a.d.csv',
           'raw2.a.b.c.d.a.csv',
           'raw1.a.csv.removed',      # <-- specify which files to rm
           'raw2.a.b.c.csv.removed',  # <-- specify which files to rm
```

and here's the dag:

```
$ snakemake --dag all | dot -Tpng > dag.png
```

[image]